# How to use grep() function to identify first and last portion of variable name in r

Tags: r, reshape

I am trying to produce an average score variable for each of two populations using the grep() function. All of my code runs, but there isn't a difference between the avgScore.pop1 and avgScore.pop2 variable values, which I think has to do with the fact that the population identifier is at the end of the variable name.

Here is an example of the code I am using:

```
rm(list = ls())

measure <- c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6",
         "m1", "m2", "m3", "m4", "m5", "m6")
population <- c("pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1",
           "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2",
           "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1",
           "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2",
           "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1",
           "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2",
           "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1", "pop1",
           "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2", "pop2")
name <- c("name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1",
     "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1", "name1",
     "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2",
     "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2", "name2",
     "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3",
     "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3", "name3",
     "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4",
     "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4", "name4")
facility <- c("fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1",
         "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1",
         "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1",
         "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1", "fac1",
         "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",
         "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",  "fac2",
         "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3",
         "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3", "fac3")
set.seed(12); denominator <- runif(48, 10, 100)
set.seed(12); score <- runif(48, 0, 1)


dat <- data.frame(name, facility, population, measure, denominator, score)

wide1 <- reshape(data=dat,
             idvar= c("name", "facility", "population"),
             timevar = "measure", 
             direction="wide")
wide2 <- reshape(data=wide1,
             idvar = c("name", "facility"),
             timevar= "population",
             direction="wide")

wide2$avgScore.pop1 <- rowSums(wide2[, grep("score.", names(wide2), '.pop1')], na.rm=T)/ 6
wide2$avgScore.pop2 <- rowSums(wide2[, grep("score.", names(wide2), '.pop2')], na.rm=T)/ 6

wide2$avgDenom.pop1 <- rowSums(wide2[, grep("denominator.", names(wide2), '.pop1')], na.rm=T)/ 6
wide2$avgDenom.pop2 <- rowSums(wide2[, grep("denominator.", names(wide2), '.pop2')], na.rm=T)/ 6
```

Any ideas of how to sum across all measures for each population for score and denominator are greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: I think you're confusing `grep` with `paste` / `paste0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `paste0`. `grep` searches for a regex pattern in a character vector. You want to paste multiple strings together. Simply replace `grep` with `paste0` in your code:

```
wide2$avgScore.pop1 <- rowSums(wide2[, paste0("score.", names(wide2), '.pop1')],
                               na.rm=T)/ 6

wide2$avgScore.pop2 <- rowSums(wide2[, paste0("score.", names(wide2), '.pop2')],
                               na.rm=T)/ 6
```

You would use `grep` here if you wanted to find all the variables that, for example, started with "score." and ended with ".pop1"

```
grep("score\\.[^.]+\\.pop1", colnames(wide2))
```

would return roughly the same as:

```
paste0("score.", names(wide2), ".pop1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible you are looking for aggregate?

```
> aggregate(score ~ population + measure, dat, sum)
   population measure    score
1        pop1      m1 1.357344
2        pop2      m1 2.062984
3        pop1      m2 2.310233
4        pop2      m2 1.845279
5        pop1      m3 2.096953
6        pop2      m3 1.968227
7        pop1      m4 1.288433
8        pop2      m4 1.705252
9        pop1      m5 1.654866
10       pop2      m5 1.504966
11       pop1      m6 1.774900
12       pop2      m6 2.510683
```

Or with dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
 group_by(population, measure) %>% 
 summarize(sum(score))

# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   population [?]
   population measure `sum(score)`
       <fctr>  <fctr>        <dbl>
 1       pop1      m1     1.357344
 2       pop1      m2     2.310233
 3       pop1      m3     2.096953
 4       pop1      m4     1.288433
 5       pop1      m5     1.654866
 6       pop1      m6     1.774900
 7       pop2      m1     2.062984
 8       pop2      m2     1.845279
 9       pop2      m3     1.968227
10       pop2      m4     1.705252
11       pop2      m5     1.504966
12       pop2      m6     2.510683
```

Comment: This is not quite what I am hoping for. I still want each row to correspond to a name, with the average score variables representing an average for each name across the measure for the two different populations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
wide2$avgScore.pop1 <- rowSums(wide2[, grepl('.pop1', names(wide2))],na.rm=T)/ 6
wide2$avgScore.pop2 <- rowSums(wide2[, grepl('.pop2', names(wide2))], na.rm=T)/ 6
```

This should do what you want. It uses `grepl` to match all names that end on ".pop1" and "pop2" respectively and returns a logical vector to indicate the indices of the variables to sum over.

Not sure if that's what you're after, but in order to get the numbers, there is also simpler solution, just using your original data:

```
library(dplyr)
averages <- dat %>%
  group_by(population, name, facility) %>%
  summarize(avScore=mean(score))
```

Comment: This does work; however, your solution made me realize I have over simplified my example. I also have a denominator variable (how my observations the measure could have applied to) which will also have the .measure.population nomenclature. I am hoping to get averages for denominator for each population too. I have updated the original question. Any ideas? Thanks!